# Cleaning an Aspen Horizontal Evaporator Coil

Tags: hvac

I'm a first time homeowner and looking for advice on cleaning out my Aspen horizontal plenum evaporator coil installed in our attic. The plenum is mostly sheet metal with part of the sides constructed from duct board.

There doesn't appear to be an obvious access panel. All edges are covered in a thick layer of mastic. But close inspection revealed screws and a seam on top. Product literature makes mention of "split access doors on top of the coil for easy service".

Does anyone have experience with Aspen or similar units? Assuming I can do this without damaging any coolant lines, is it as simple as removing the mastic and unscrewing the access door? Removing the access door seems to require removable of the line set bushings and resealing the penetrations afterward. That's not exactly "easy service" if you ask me.

[image: Installed to the right of downflow air handler]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Evaporator coils in Air handlers are not designed for the homeowner to service.
The "easy service..." description is for the HVAC professionals.

Unscrewing the panel and removing the tape is the only way to access the coils.

There is not a usual or normal reason to clean the evap coils.  The air that is drawn or pushed through the coils is filtered in the home at the air return.

In my location 95% of the homes have AC systems with this type of Air Handler and nobody services it themselves. Most go their entire lifespans without being opened up for any reason.  However if one is opened it is wise to leave that to the professionals.